# Running Facebook SDK for Android, samples

Tags: android, facebook

Could please someone confirm that, in order to run
the official Android Samples from the Facebook Android SDK,
you can run them

WITHOUT 1) generating a public-private key hash (keytool-openssl)
  and writing it into "developer settings" [developer settings->sample app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/settings?tab=developer&section=sampleapp&view)

IF YOU ALTERNATIVELY DO 2) create a new "developer application" MyApp, fill in the data and provide for it a generated key-hash

The fact is that I DO NOT provided a key to facebook (posibility 1), but was able to run those samples (even HelloFacebookSample that requires login). Is it because I have created my app with its key before running the samples (posibility 2)?

Comment: Do you have the Facebook app installed on your device? the key hash is used for SSO, but not the web dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simplest apps, such as ProfilePictureSample, will run immediately. If you want to run those that involve authentication, however, you will need to perform one extra step of configuration, which is to provide your Android key hash to Facebook.

For more information check the link under Run the Samples

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: Well the fact is that I DO NOT provided that key to facebook, but was able to run those samples. Is it because I have created my app with its key before running the samples? That is the point.

Comment: you don't need key for running apps such as ProfilePictureSample sample from the facebook sdk samples. For this you are not logged into facebook .If you want to run HelloFacebookSample sample then you require they key. You need to login for this sample and you require the key

Comment: I ran HelloFacebookSample without the key, really. I put user-password when prompted in the login dialog, but I insist that I did not put the key in "developer settings" of the facebook web. So I guess maybe it was because I had previously created "my app" with a key for it.

Comment: could be . i suggest you go through the link posted in the answer. ProfilePictureSample: demonstrates non-logged-in usage of the profile picture control. This is what the link quotes. HelloFacebookSample: an all-round sample that demonstrates profile access, status updates and photo uploading for which you require the key suggesting you might have the key already if you logged in

Comment: Don't know what to think, hence the question here !

Comment: well the answer is right there in the link posted in the answer.

Comment: Well, the docs says "But to bypass this check for the SDK samples and to get them up and running quickly, you can add your key hash". YOU CAN or *YOU MUST*?